# How to access Enterprise Custom Lookup Fields of Project Server 2013 in project site

Tags: sharepoint, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

I am running project server 2013 on SharePoint and I want to access enterprise lookup fields in project site. E.g in subsite I want to know project name, customer name and all other fields which I created in PDP in main pwa 2013.

How to access parent level custom fields in sub-site? Project server 2013

Answer (score 0):

Question seems to be having answer within it.   Process is same for PDP as well as subsite.

```
Edit the page
Add Webpart
Select Project server from the list
Select basic and add it.
Modify it and add the fields you want.
```